# How to add scrollbar to Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, scrollbar

I have a Recyclerview in my app, but I can't add scrollbar to it. I tried every possible solution in web. Most solutions are not suitable for current system. In the solution I came closest to, the bar becomes tiny when scroll down and cannot be touched with a finger. So I need your help.

Here my xml

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".WordListFragment"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/word_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager" />
    
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/clear_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/no_data"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="?colorPrimaryDark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/scrollToTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_up_black_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/word_list"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

my java file

````
{
    private final Context context;
    ArrayList<Word> data_list;
    private int[] theme_array;
    ToggleButton selected_theme;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Word> data_list)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.data_list = data_list;
    }

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        theme_array=new int[]{R.style.AppTheme
                ,R.style.GreenTheme
                ,R.style.RedTheme
                ,R.style.PurpleTheme
                ,R.style.TealTheme
                ,R.style.GreenBlueTheme
                ,R.style.BlueGrayTheme
                ,R.style.PinkTheme
                ,R.style.DarkBlueTheme
                ,R.style.DarkYellowTheme
                ,R.style.BrownTheme
                ,R.style.DarkRedTheme};
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        int id=R.layout.word_list_item;
        if (data_list==null)
            id=R.layout.theme_chooser;
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(id, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        if (data_list==null)
        {
            if (theme_array[position]==MainActivity.preferences.getInt(context.getString(R.string.theme_pref),R.style.AppTheme))
            {
                holder.color_btn.setChecked(true);
                selected_theme=holder.color_btn;
            }
            TypedArray array=context.obtainStyledAttributes(theme_array[position],new int[]{R.attr.colorPrimary});
            Drawable drawable= Objects.requireNonNull(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), R.drawable.color_state, null)).mutate();
            int color=array.getColor(0, Color.WHITE);
            drawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            drawable=getDrawable(color,drawable);
            holder.color_btn.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
            return;
        }
        final Word tmp=data_list.get(position);
        if (MainActivity.isSecond)
            holder.title.setText(tmp.getMeaning());
        else
            holder.title.setText(tmp.getWord());


        if (tmp.isUserAdded())
            holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_added).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else
            holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_added).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        ((View)holder.title.getParent()).setOnClickListener(view -> context.startActivity(new Intent(context,DetailActivity.class)
        .putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_DETAILS,tmp)));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        if (data_list==null)
            return theme_array.length;
        return data_list.size();

    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView title;
        ToggleButton color_btn;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            if (data_list!=null)
                title=itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_title);
            else
            {
                color_btn = (ToggleButton) itemView;
                color_btn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                    if (color_btn.isChecked())
                    {
                        if (selected_theme!=null)
                            selected_theme.setChecked(false);
                        selected_theme=color_btn;
                        MainActivity.preferences.edit().putInt(context.getString(R.string.theme_pref),theme_array[getAdapterPosition()]).apply();
                        ((Activity)context).recreate();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    Drawable getDrawable(int  color,Drawable main_drawable)
    {
        Drawable drawable=ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_check_black_24dp,null);
        StateListDrawable stateListDrawable=new StateListDrawable();
        LayerDrawable layerDrawable=new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{main_drawable,drawable});
        stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked},layerDrawable);
        stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{},main_drawable);
        return stateListDrawable;
    }
} ```
````

Comment: do you want like this https://github.com/plusCubed/recycler-fast-scroll ?

Comment: yes it would be great but this is the repository from 6 years ago. I don't think it still works

Comment: I just showed the first one for example) or another earlier https://github.com/L4Digital/FastScroll  you can disable the popup if you need